# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: django

I know there is existing title about this, but there question is different from mine. So here's my problem. I use context processor to display user name. It's working but my sentry detect an error yesterday.

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Here is my code:

```
def display_name(request):
    try:
        name = "{0} {1}".format(request.user.first_name, request.user.last_name)
        name = name.strip()
        if not name:
            name = request.user.username
    except AttributeError:
        name = None

    return {'display_name': name,}
```

What's the cause of this? Or the user input character for their name?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's basically a user input problem.

Text encodings are a whole "thing" and hard to get into, but in a nut shell, a user entered a Unicode character that can't easily be mapped to an ASCII character.

You can fix this by changing this:

```
name = "{0} {1}".format(request.user.first_name, request.user.last_name)
```

To this:

```
name = u"{0} {1}".format(request.user.first_name, request.user.last_name)
```

This tells Python to treat the string as a unicode string (which has all the normal functions as an ascii string).

Comment: before I mark your answer. Is it ok to use {{user.get_full_name}} in the template and it will not detect ascii error?

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. Django's built-in stuff always (usually) returns unicode strings.