# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u200b' in position 12: ordinal not in range(128) even though add u before every string

Tags: python, httpconnection

My urllib code are below:

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import http.client
import urllib.parse

host = u"​www.cloudflare.com"
url = u"%s:80" % host
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(url)

method = u"GET"

request_url = u"https://%s" % host


headers = {
    u"Host": host,
    u"Accept": u"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    u"Accept-Encoding": u"gzip, deflate, br",
    u"User-Agent":  u"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36", #"Android-ALI-Moblie 1.3.0",
    u"Content-Type": u"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    u"Cookie": u"spreadCode=789789; md5Password=true; JSESSIONID=25DE5EBD2C30D10A505FA70B64D8EA03",
    u"Accept-Language": u"zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    u"Cache-Control": u"max-age=0",
    u"Connection": u"keep-alive",
    u"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": u"1",
}

conn.request(method=method, url=request_url, headers=headers)  # this line get error

response = conn.getresponse()

print(response.status, response.reason)

response_data = response.read()
print(response_data)

response_headers = response.getheaders()
print(response_headers)

response_head_cookie = response.getheader('Set-Cookie')
print(response_head_cookie)

conn.close()
```

when I run my code, there get issue:

```
File "/Users/dele/Desktop/TestPython/HTTPConnection/test_HTTPConnection.py", line 38, in <module>
...
self._output(request.encode('ascii'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u200b' in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I also searched those posts: [questions/15084194](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084194/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xe9-in-position-1)

they all say add `u` before each string. but mine still get error.

---

**EDIT -01**

I changed my code to below:

```
import http.client

host="www.cloudflare.com"
url="%s:80" % host
conn=http.client.HTTPConnection(url)

method = "GET"

request_url = "https://%s" % host

headers = {
    "Host": "​www.cloudflare.com",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
    "User-Agent": "Android-ALI-Moblie 1.3.0",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    "Connection": "Keep-Alive"
}

conn.request(method=method, url=request_url, headers=headers)

response = conn.getresponse()

print(response.status, response.reason)

response_data = response.read()
print(response_data)

response_headers = response.getheaders()
print(response_headers)

response_head_cookie = response.getheader('Set-Cookie')
print(response_head_cookie)

conn.close()
```

but still get this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u200b' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Comment: Python 3 strings are Unicode already, there's no need for the `u` prefix. The error complains about *ASCII*, not Unicode. `request.encode('ascii')` will try to encode the Unicode string using the 7-bit US-ASCII encoding and fail as US-ASCII contains only the first 127 characters. It's not even enough for English words or names with diacriticts, eg `Brontë`.

Answer (score 0):

`\u200b` is the ZERO WIDTH SPACE character; looks like somewhere in your code, you've accidentally pasted this (essentially invisible) character, probably in the `headers`.

Try looping through the headers and running each item through `.encode('ascii', errors='xmlcharrefreplace')`; that should show you where the extraneous character is hiding, then you can delete it.

**EDIT:** Found it; your `host` variable has the `\u200b` character at the beginning. You need to delete the invisible character between `host = u"` and `www.cloudflare.com"`.

Comment: is there a way to filter out all the invisible characters? I delete all, but still get this issue.

Comment: You can filter them out, but really you need to figure out how they got there and change some part of your process so they don't get there in the first place. Filtering them in bulk is going to just lead to trouble down the road, either when they appear somewhere they can't be filtered, or (conversely) when they're significant and need to be kept.